# Printing the output that is a list of file names to a text file

Tags: python

I have made a Python program that checks the files in a folder and returns a list of the ones that end with .txt. Now i want to output that to a file. Here is my code:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys

f=open("E:\\test.txt",'w')
f.write('')

path=os.path.abspath("E:\\test")
def print_result():
    print(name)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".txt"):
            print_result()

Version 1:

alist=[print_name]            
alist.append(print_result)
f=open("E:\\test.txt", 'a')
f.writelines(alist)

Version 2:

alist=name
alist.append(name)
f = open("E:\\test.txt",'a')
print (name)

Version 3:

frame=print_result
saveout = sys.stdout
fsock = open("E:\\test.txt", 'a')
sys.stdout = fsock
print (frame)
sys.stdout = saveout`enter code here`

As you can see i have tried diferent types. The thing is that i only get the following in the file, instead of the actual output list:

<function print_result at 0x004F6DB0>
```

Comment: Why do you define a function `print_result` that does absolutely nothing but print? Just `print(name)` instead of `print_result()`. Have you looked at any tutorial or documentation for file I/O? They all would help you with this basic task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access not only the *.txt files in the current working directory but also in any sub-directories, recursively, which is what I think you were trying to achieve with the `os.walk()` reference, try the following:

```
import os
def GetFiles(dir,f):
    basedir = dir
    subdirs = []
    for fname in os.listdir(dir):
        fileName = os.path.join(basedir, fname)
        if os.path.isfile(fileName):
            if fileName.endswith(".txt"):
                f.write(fileName+"\n")
                print fileName
        elif os.path.isdir(fileName):
            subdirs.append(fileName)
    for subdir in subdirs:
        GetFiles(subdir,f)
f=open("test.txt",'w')
GetFiles('./',f)
f.close()
```

This will list the files ending with ".txt" in the current working directory and all sub-directories, putting the path and file-name in the file test.txt

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a little simpler using a [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
import glob

txtfiles = glob.glob('E:\\test\\*.txt')
with open('E:\\test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for txtfile in txtfiles:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(txtfile))
```

Comment: I appreciate that the OP has accepted that this works but the original code used `os.walk()` so using `glob` isn't going to produce the same results, as it will not dig down into sub-directories.

Comment: @MihaiGhimpu If you think that this is the correct answer, you should accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it

Answer (score 0):

**You need to get all the files in a directory**

> assume you have a path of directory as *"/home/ubuntu/test"* and you want to write a result in a file *"result.txt"*

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir("/home/ubuntu/test") if isfile(join("/home/ubuntu/test",f)) ]

with open ("/home/ubuntu/result.txt","w")as fp:
  for line in onlyfiles:
    fp.write(line+"\n")
```

> Then got to *"/home/ubuntu/"* and open *result.txt*. You will se the name of the files there